# How does this Python code works? [Character Picture Grid]

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I saw this Project in the book, Automate the Boring stuff with Python, and I was just going great with all the projects and all that, but I saw the project " Character Picture Grid ", and I was completely lost. And I had look here, and I found a code for Character Picture Grid

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
   ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
   ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
   ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
   ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
   ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
   ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
   ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
   ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

def gridOutput(grid):
    for s in range(len(grid[0])):
        print()
        for i in range(len(grid)):
            print(grid[i][s],end='')
gridOutput(grid)
```

So my question is, can someone, please explain to me how this code works, **thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let say there are two grids, the input grid and the output grid.

```
# The input grid have 9 rows with 6 items each
grid = [
   ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
   ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
   ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
   ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
   ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
   ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
   ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
   ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
   ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
]

def gridOutput(grid):
    # len(grid[0]) get the length of the first row in input grid, which is 6 for 6 items,
    # then for s in range(6) loop the following print 6 times, which means 6 rows in our output grid.
    for s in range(len(grid[0])):
        print()
        # len(grid) get the length of input grid, which is the row numbers 9,
        # then for i in range(9) means we will 9 items for each row. 
        for i in range(len(grid)):
            # this is the interesting part, we only take one item of each row in input grid
            # (grid[0][0], grid[1][0] ... grid[8][0]), to our new row in output grid.
            print(grid[i][s],end='')
gridOutput(grid)
```

The output grid will be the same as input grid if you swap the for-loop:

```
def gridOutput(grid):
    # 9 rows
    for i in range(len(grid)):
        print()
        # 6 items
        for s in range(len(grid[0])):
            # take all items of each row in input grid (grid[0][0], grid[0][1] ... grid[0][5])
            print(grid[i][s], end='')
gridOutput(grid)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm hearing you complain "this code is unclear".
Ok, fair enough, let me try out some revised code
that attempts to clarify it.
Introducing a pair of variables might help explain
what the expressions mean.

There is an arbitrary decision about [x][y] vs [y][x] (90° flip)
that I won't try to change here.
(And no, I have no idea what `s` stands for.)

```
def grid_output(grid):
    width, height = len(grid), len(grid[0])
    assert (width, height) == (9, 6)
    for j in range(height):
        print()
        for i in range(width):
            assert len(grid[i]) == height
            print(grid[i][j], end='')
```

An important property of the input grid
is that each row shall have identical length.
The 2nd assert verifies that.